# Malloc always returns a NULL pointer; Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c++, visual-studio, malloc, realloc, calloc

This may be a duplicate question but I checked out other question like this and never really found what I was looking for (or so i believe).

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{   
    char* s = (char*)malloc(2 * sizeof(char));

    *s = 'M';

    s++;

    *s = 'I';

    std::cout << s[-1] << s[0] << s[1];
}
```

Output:

```
MI²
```

My problem is that, whenever I try to use `malloc`/`calloc`/`realloc` I always have the same error message pop up that says that s (cf. code above) is an 'unreferenced NULL-pointer'.

I really don't see the problem here. Especially because both 'M' and 'I' have been allocated to the array I initialized via malloc, but they're in odd places. I'd expect: `s[0] = 'M`' and `s[1] = 'I'` but instead it's `s[-1] = 'M'` and `s[0] = 'I'`, which I find rather strange.

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Use ~~~ before and after your code block.

Comment: When posting a question, there is a help button (`?`). You can use that to read about how to format a question.

Comment: You changed s when you did `s++;` so now s points at one past the memory you allocated. So s[-1] points back to where the 'M' was set and s[1] points is memory you didn't allocate.

Comment: You do know that `s++;` MODIFIES `s`, right?

Comment: Tactical note: `sizeof (char)` is defined by the C++ Standard to always be 1. Even on a freaky-deaky old Cray with a 32 bit `char`.

Comment: Does it really say _"unreferenced "_? Can you copy/paste the message into the question please? `std::cout << s[-1] << s[0] << s[1];` _must_ be out of bounds. You've allocated space for `2` `char`s. You are **dereferencing** `3` pointers. `s[1]` is out of the allocated space so ... _undefined behavior_.

Comment: I guess the warning says "dereferencing a NULL pointer" ... which is a warning about a *possibility*. You should always check the return value of calls the `malloc` and its cousins, and have code to handle the error when it actually *does* return NULL.

Comment: An even more subtle problem is that _even if_ `s[something]` had been within allocated territory (if you'd used `malloc(3)`) but you only assigned values to `2` of those `3` memory slots,  it'd be _undefined behavior_. Since it's C++, dereferencing uninitialized memory should lead to UB. Unlike in C, the lifetime of objects matters to a high degree when compilers tries to optimize things.

Comment: From a simple point of view, `*s = 'I'`, then `s[0]='I'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be clear, that message is a warning by the compiler, its not that you are getting null from malloc, it warns that you might and have not checked

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/c6011?view=msvc-170

The message goes away if you do

```
char* s = (char*)malloc(2 * sizeof(char));
if (s != NULL)
{
    *s = 'M';

    s++;

    *s = 'I';

    std::cout << s[-1] << s[0] << s[1];
}
```

There is another warning though

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/c6200?view=msvc-170

This is warning that `s[-1]` looks very odd. Its ignoring the fact that you did s++ earlier which makes this ok.

Whats not ok is

```
 std::cout << s[-1] << s[0] << s[1];
 ------------------------------*****
```

this is accessing data beyond the end of the allocation, result is Undefined Behavior.

if you do

```
int main()
{
    char* s = (char*)malloc(2 * sizeof(char));
    if (s != NULL)
    {
        s[0] = 'M';

        

        s[1] = 'I';

        std::cout << s[0] << s[1] << s[2];
    }
}
```

which is a much more straightforward way of doing the same thing then VS will warn you about that s[2] being out of bounds

Comment: Hey, thanks alot for your reply. Your answer combined with @Hackerman 's reply helped me understand (and also fix) my problem. Thank you :))

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have changed s in the line `s++;`
`s` points to the base of your allocation. So when you increment it, it's natural that s[0] points to 'I'.

If you want to assign the 2nd position of your memory allocation, or the ith for that matter, you can either use this `s[i] = 'M';`, or you can do this: `*(s+i) = 'M';`.\

But the former is the better practice, since it's more readable. I believe most people would pause upon facing the latter, as it's quite rare to see these days.

### Additional Info

In fact, when you use `s[i] = 'M';`, the compiler just translates it to `*(s+i) = 'M';`. So this `[]` is just an operator that is defined on the pointer type, and it simply adds its argument, which is named `i` in most cases, to the base of the pointer.

Comment: Good but it doesn't seem to me that it is enough to help the user. you have ignored the real problem of the matter

Comment: Well, I thought I explained the problem, suggested a solution with a justification, and added some information.

Comment: Hey, thank you very much for your reply :). Using both your and @pm100 's answer I finally understand my problem. Thanks for helping out :)). Also thank you for the heads up in the additional info. Didn't know that (even though it might seem obvious) and helped deepen my understanding of the topic even more :)

Comment: Glad I could help! Could you please upvote the answer? I am new here and trying to gain some reputation XD.

Comment: @Hackerman I already tried doing that when you left your reply but couldn't bc i didn't / still don't have enough reputation for that...